# Convert String to DateTime Object and Add it to total time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have string list which contains spent time in `hh:mm:ss` as string
like

```
00:00:40
00:01:00
00:02:10
```

I want to add these values and show it to user as

```
Total Time: 00:03:50
```

I can parse each time value to date time but how can I add them to show the result show above.

Here is how I am parsing the string to DateTime

```
foreach(string itm in TimeList)
{
    DateTime sTime = DateTime.ParseExact(itm , "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parsing operation is fine. But you assign the result to your `sTime` in *every* iteration, that's why you lost all of the data *except* the last one.

But more important, instead of `DateTime`, I would parse them to [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) instead which fits better to your data since it is a *time interval*.

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "00:00:40",
    "00:01:00",
    "00:02:10"
};

var total = TimeSpan.Zero;

foreach (var item in list)
{
    total += TimeSpan.ParseExact(item, "hh\\:mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Now you can format your `total` and show to user like;

```
string.Format("Total Time: {0}", 
               total.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

> It seems ParseExact is not available in DotNet 3.5

Then you can use [`TimeSpan.Parse` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse) which is available since .NET 1.0 version. But I *strongly* suggest to you consider to upgrade your framework version *if* you can.

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    total += TimeSpan.Parse(item);
}
```

Comment: It seems ParseExact is not available in DotNet 3.5, Sorry I forgot to mention DotNet Framework.

Comment: @AdilWaqar That's ok. You can use `TimeSpan.Parse` method instead since it's available since .NET 1.0 version. But why you _still_ use .NET 3.5? It is quite old. Please consider to update it.

Comment: Yes it worked, Thanks, The app is quit old its just a small update in it,

Answer (score 1):

You should use `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime`, since `00:00:40` means *40 seconds* and not *40 seconds after midnight*. You can use *Linq* to sum up the values:

```
List<String> times = new List<String>() {
  "00:00:40",
  "00:01:00",
  "00:02:10"};

var totalTime = new TimeSpan(times
  .Select(item => TimeSpan.Parse(item).Ticks)
  .Sum());

// 00:03:50
Console.Write("Total Time: {0}", totalTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
var TimeList = new [] { "00:00:40", "00:01:00", "00:02:10" };

var TotalTime =
    TimeList
        .Select(itm => TimeSpan.Parse(itm))
        .Aggregate((ts0, ts1) => ts1.Add(ts0));

Console.WriteLine("Total Time: {0}", TotalTime);
```

That gives me:

```
Total Time: 00:03:50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeSpan` as storage

```
var spent = TimeSpan.FromTicks(TimeList.Sum(i => TimeSpan.Parse(i).Ticks));
```

Then print the spent as the format